# Create influxDB from DockerFile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, influxdb

I have to create an influxDB from DockerFile. My DockerFile is:

```
FROM influxdb:1.7.6

ENV TZ=America/Los_Angeles

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

run  \
  -e INFLUXDB_DB=db0 -e INFLUXDB_ADMIN_ENABLED=true \
  -e INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER=admin -e INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD=supersecretpassword \
  -e INFLUXDB_USER=telegraf -e INFLUXDB_USER_PASSWORD=secretpassword \
  -v $PWD:/var/lib/influxdb \
  influxdb /init-influxdb.sh
```

I saw this create influxDB script from (http://man.hubwiz.com/docset/Docker.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/docs.docker.com/samples/library/influxdb.html). Now when i run **docker build -t myinfluximage .** from DockerFile directory, i get the following:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/4 : FROM influxdb:1.7.6
1.7.6: Pulling from library/influxdb
6f2f362378c5: Pull complete
494c27a8a6b8: Pull complete
7596bb83081b: Pull complete
058194e87993: Pull complete
9382c8196521: Pull complete
651ab765a68f: Pull complete
c8620b54be93: Pull complete
5386872a43f3: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:af07db2e2040b27d4ae4c57b51729503802d22c1632893fe63ea054afe632ecc
Status: Downloaded newer image for influxdb:1.7.6
---> 8a4e8eda54c1
Step 2/4 : ENV TZ=America/Los_Angeles
---> Running in 0a81e476ec84
Removing intermediate container 0a81e476ec84
---> 5144c757b63f
Step 3/4 : RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
---> Running in b619435af05a
Removing intermediate container b619435af05a
---> adee5c481c4a
Step 4/4 : run        -e INFLUXDB_DB=db0 -e INFLUXDB_ADMIN_ENABLED=true       -e INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER=admin -e INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD=supersecretpassword       -e INFLUXDB_USER=telegraf -e INFLUXDB_USER_PASSWORD=secretpassword       -v $PWD:/var/lib/influxdb       influxdb /init-influxdb.sh
---> Running in 14312c7bd5f4
/bin/sh: 0: Illegal option -
The command '/bin/sh -c -e INFLUXDB_DB=db0 -e INFLUXDB_ADMIN_ENABLED=true       -e INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER=admin -e INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD=supersecretpassword       -e INFLUXDB_USER=telegraf -e INFLUXDB_USER_PASSWORD=secretpassword       -v $PWD:/var/lib/influxdb       influxdb /init-influxdb.sh' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

Why i am getting the exception on create database script. What can be the possible issue ?

Comment: In the same way your first line `RUN ln ...` runs the `ln` shell command, your second line `RUN -e ...` tries to run a command `-e`, but the shell has trouble making sense of this.

Comment: so how should i resolve this ? @DavidMaze